# how to pass props to react handler component

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

How can i pass props to react handler component ?

my code is as bellow:

```
var Dashboard = require('./Dashboard');
var Comments = require('./Comments');

var Index = React.createClass({
```

Comment: Did u missing something?

Comment: Please edit the code with `CTRL + K` and provide the rest of the code so we can help you better.

Comment: Please complete the question if you want anybody to help you. Currently, It is unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

```
var Index = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { input1: '', input2: '' };
    },
    handleinput1Change: function (e) {
        this.setState({ input1: e.target.value });
    },
    handleinput2Change : function (e) {
        this.setState({ input2: e.target.value });
    },
    handleSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text1 = this.state.input1.trim();
        var text2 = this.state.input2.trim();
        if (!text1 || !text2) {
            return;
        }
        this.props.onCommentSubmit({ input1: text1, input2: text2 });
        this.setState({ input1: '', input2: '' });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter something"
                    value={this.state.input1}
                    onChange={this.handleinput1Change}
                />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter something"
                    value={this.state.input2}
                    onChange={this.handleinput2Change} />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```